# Javascript to hover a post in Tinyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently had to host an Tinyboard imageboard. And there is a Javascript which should popup a post when you hover on that post ID. But the script doesn't seem to work. To be specific there is javascript: https://github.com/savetheinternet/Tinyboard/blob/master/js/post-hover.js
And I'm completely begginer at js so I have no idea what does what and what could be wrong with it. If  for some reason you would want to see that imageboard by yourself go there: 3 7 0 c h a n . l t /int

Answer (score 1):

The current upstream Tinyboard is mostly inactive, they pulled some of my commits while breaking code and the upstream is missing some security fixes (there is one unpatched XSS vulnerability).

If you want to have a working Tinyboard out of the box, please use my fork:

- https://int.vichan.net/devel/

Otherwise, you can fix them by hand, check out the latest issues:

- https://github.com/savetheinternet/Tinyboard/issues